# how to install packages which is not in the cache with python

Tags: apt, package-management, python, apt-cache

i install packages in my application using python apt. Some example:

```
import apt
cache = apt.cache.Cache()
pkg = cache["brukkon"]
pkg.mark_install()
cache.commit()
```

In this example, brukkon is not in the cache, hence this package cannot be downloaded. Also no available icon exists for this package in usr/share/app-install/icons .In ubuntu software center, this package is seen proprietary, and its cost is 7 dollar. However, package's information can be seen in ubuntu software center. But how? **How can i access proprietary package's informations although these packages is not in  cache?**

Also, some of these proprietary packages are no cost. But in order to install these packages you need to click buy button, then login with your ubuntu one account. One example package is senetonline. This package too is not in cache. Thus i can neither install it nor access the package's details with python apt.

With these reasons i can only use packages which exists in cache. **How can i use other packages in my app?**

Thanks in advance.